# Converting VC++ 6 project to VC++2010 with MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, porting

So, I have this code that hasn't been touched since '99, and was made with VS6. I need to be able to compile and change some stuff in the code, SO, after trying the VS2010 conversion wizard, I get a few errors saying certain header files couldnt be found.: afxwin.h , and one other header file that's related to the program. I know it's using MFC, and since I have NOT the express edition of VS, but the full version, I should have all the dependencies required, right?

So I guess my question is: what would be the best way to convert a VS file thats **several** versions old? Will I have to create a new 2010 C++ proj, and just manually port over all the files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Create New Project from Existing Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx) if the conversion is problematic.

VC++ 10 is a lot better on conformance to the standard, so you may find the VC++ 6 source code no longer compiles even when you have a working project file (a good thing).  Fixing such problems up is not generally too hard.